# Python: a website forbidding me from reading values using website API links

Tags: python, python-requests

So on the Website [ROBLOX.com](https://www.roblox.com/), the currency is Robux, I'm trying to make a program that monitors the value of the users currency.

The site has it's on API for viewing stuff.
For example, if I wanted to view my own Robux it would be a simple link,

https://api.roblox.com/currency/balance

But the problem is...

`print(requests.session().get("https://api.roblox.com/currency/balance").text)`

It reads a message from ROBLOX on the site saying that it's `Forbidden`.
And the program doing what it's told to do, prints the message telling me it's a forbidden action.

The same with when I use `json` function.

So, when I enter the link myself as expected it returns
`{ ROBUX : "0" }`.
Why would they even do this? It's not like Bot devs care about their bots having money?

Any idea's on how to Bypass?

Comment: How does the website know your userid? Have you logged in? In python? `Why would they even do this` - what, require you to log in before giving your personal information?

Comment: Check your cookies in the browser. Use the same cookies in your requests call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "https://api.roblox.com/currency/balance" requires you to view information that is user-specific. Using a browser, you would have to login to "https://www.roblox.com" before you can view your balance. To by pass this:

Step1: go to "https://www.roblox.com" and login

Step2: Assume you are using Chrome, right click and click Inspect

Step3: On the top, there is a bar with a button called "Network", click it

Step4: refresh the page

Step5: There is a selection panel on your left, scroll all the way up to see "home?nl=true". click it.

Step6: On top of the central panel, under Request Cookies, one item called 
".ROBLOSECURITY", double click its value on the right, copy the whole trunk. Then do this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
cookie_str = "your whole trunk"
r = Request("https://api.roblox.com/currency/balance", headers={'Cookie': '.ROBLOSECURITY={}'.format(cookie_str)})
response = urlopen(r)
text = response.read()
```

As Roblox has warned, never share your security data with anyone as other may be able to steal your dollar or abuse your account.

Comment: Thanks. I never though I was going to need the .ROBLOSECURITY cookie, I mean it's stupid why you need that just to view the amount.

Comment: it is for security reason. If it works, please select my answer, Thanks!